# Phonegap email composer not opening email client

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, email-client

I can't seem to make the email composer plugin work. I added it to the project using console and added the line prescribed in the readme file on the config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="de.killercodemonkey.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2" />
```

[This is the package I'm using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-email-composer)

Also, upon submitting this to PhoneGap Build, it does not list the plugin after it builds.

This is the code that I have bound to a button. The binding only happens after deviceready and any function runs are undeniably after deviceready.

```
    function SubmitToEmail()
{

    alert(1);

    email.isAvailable(
        function (isAvailable) {
            if(isAvailable)
            {
                email.open({
                to:      'john.doe@email.com',
                subject: 'Need Help!',
                body:    'Hello, my name is John Doe and I currently need help at my current location. Thanks',
                isHtml:  true
                });
            }
            else
            alert('Please configure your default email client before proceeding.'); 
        }
    );


}
```

The alert seems to trigger but anything beyond that does not work. I have tried both namespaces "cordova.plugins.email.open" and "email.open" and neither seem to work.

I'm testing my app inside the phonegap app on iOS.

I'm not sure what is it that I'm doing work here. Please help.
Thanks

**EDIT:** Is there anyway to troubleshoot this? How do I see any errors that are generated from running this code on the phonegap app? Thanks

Comment: I've had the same thing, a few times in different apps. The solution was to uninstall and then reinstall the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the phonegap build version of the plugin you have to use the source pgb

```
<plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" spec="0.8.2" source="pgb" />
```

If you want to use the npm version use

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-email-composer" spec="~0.8.2" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried all kinds of combinations including with the <gap:plugin> tag and it did not seem to be working. Not sure if it would make any difference if I build the app.